# Angular 13 & httpd24 - Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of ""

Tags: angular, apache, npm, httpd.conf, angular13

[image]

I have migrated my application from angular 10 to angular 13 and I started getting this error in browser console. I have tried most of the solution mentioned in the stackoverflow. But there is no luck. Since code was working correctly with angular 10 but after migrating to 13 I am getting MIME error in browser. Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are pointing to the correct build directory, if you are using express to run your production app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pointing to the correct build directory if you are using express to run your production app

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/project_folder")));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/project_folder/index.html"));
});
```